# Subset a list of data frames - error when writing output

Tags: r, list, for-loop, lapply, write.table

I have 4 different .csv files in 4 different locations and I want to subset them using the same criteria. Then I want to write the output in the form "originalfilename_cpt.csv" for each one of them (ideally to the original location, but I gave up on that already - don't mind writing them to the workspace and moving them manually)

Because they are in different locations, I started by reading the files individually:

```
data1 <- read.csv("Subsets\\Folder1\\data1.csv")
data2 <- read.csv("Subsets\\Folder2\\data2.csv")
data3 <- read.csv("Subsets\\Folder3\\data3.csv")
data4 <- read.csv("Subsets\\Folder4\\data4.csv")
```

Then created a list with all the files:

```
mylist <- list(data1, data2, data3, data4)
```

From here I tried 2 routes - first created a function and used lapply:

```
MyFunction <- function(file){
  clean.file <- file[(file$pingtimehrs < 3.334), ]
  write.csv(clean.file, file=paste(file, "_cpt.csv", sep=""), row.names = F)
}

lapply(mylist, MyFunction)
```

And second used a for loop:

```
for (file in mylist){
  clean.file <- file[(file$pingtimehrs < 3.334), ]
  write.csv(clean.file, file=paste(file, "_cpt.csv", sep=""), row.names = F)
}
```

I get the same error in both cases, which I suspect has to do with writing the output, as I can se my clean.file is being created (the first one, at least) and it looks right. This is the error I get:

```
Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
  invalid 'description' argument

In addition: Warning message:
In if (file == "") file <- stdout() else if (is.character(file)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Can someone please spot what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `file` seems to be a data.frame? Pasting a data.frame with `"_cpt.csv"` doesn't result in a nice file name.

Comment: `file` is each element of the list, which yes, are data frames. Is that the problem? How can I get the name of `file` then?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for (i in seq_along(mylist)){
  clean.file <- mylist[[i]][(mylist[[i]]$pingtimehrs < 3.334), ]
  write.csv(clean.file, file=paste(names(mylist)[i], "cpt.csv", sep="_"), row.names = F)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Roland! However, this is just subseting the first element in `mylist` and producing empty outputs for the other elements. It is also naming my outputs with their index in `mylist`, rather than their name - I get "1_cpt.csv" instead of "data1_cpt.csv"

Comment: I don't have a reproducible example but I suspect that your subsetting step `pingtimehrs < 3.334` is responsible for the empty outputs. I've fixed the naming issue.

Comment: Forget what I said about your code creating empty outputs - my mistake! I'll try your edit for the file names.

Comment: Well, just tried your edit and I get a file named `"_cpt.csv"`. I also typed `names(mylist)` and get `NULL`. I am a bit confused: why doesn't my list know it's elements' names?

Comment: OK, I get that my list is an unnamed list. I tried to create a named list instead, but unless I name each element of the list exactly the same as the original file name, I still won't have my final output named "originalfilename_cpt.csv" (this seems simple enough with `data1` and `data1.csv`, but not as much with the real file names).
So I think this route will be complicating, instead of simplifying the code and the task - I will have to think of something else.
But thank you for your help anyway, at least I understand now where the problem was!